# checking Internet connection with HttpClient

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am having difficulties to understand on how the bellow code could handle occasional internet connection loss. Ideally I would like to pause the app, once the connection is lost, and resume when it is up again. Is there any guideline on how to do it?

```
HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
clientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler) { MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 1000000 };

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(Url, ct);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following example is not a direct solution, but it is an example I built to show how to return "pre-canned" content to requests whilst offline and then return back online when connectivity is restored.  If you can get what I'm doing here, building what you want should be fairly easy.

```
        [Fact]
        public async Task Getting_a_response_when_offline()
        {
            var offlineHandler = new OfflineHandler(new HttpClientHandler(), new Uri("http://oak:1001/status"));
            offlineHandler.AddOfflineResponse(new Uri("http://oak:1001/ServerNotRunning"), 
                new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NonAuthoritativeInformation)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent("Here's an old copy of the information while we are offline.")
                });

            var httpClient = new HttpClient(offlineHandler);

            var retry = true;

            while (retry)
            {
                var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri("http://oak:1001/ServerNotRunning"));

                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) retry = false;
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
        }


        public class OfflineHandler : DelegatingHandler
        {
            private readonly Uri _statusMonitorUri;
            private readonly Dictionary<Uri, HttpResponseMessage> _offlineResponses = new Dictionary<Uri, HttpResponseMessage>();
            private bool _isOffline = false;
            private Timer _timer;

            public OfflineHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler, Uri statusMonitorUri)
            {
                _statusMonitorUri = statusMonitorUri;
                InnerHandler = innerHandler;
            }

            public void AddOfflineResponse(Uri uri, HttpResponseMessage response)
            {
                _offlineResponses.Add(uri,response);
            }

            protected  async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                if (_isOffline == true) return OfflineResponse(request);

                try
                {
                    var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable || response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadGateway)
                    {
                        MonitorOfflineState();
                        return OfflineResponse(request);
                    }
                    return response;
                }
                catch (WebException ex)
                {
                    MonitorOfflineState();
                    return OfflineResponse(request);
                }

            }

            private void MonitorOfflineState()
            {
                _isOffline = true;
                _timer = new Timer( async state =>
                {
                    var request = new HttpRequestMessage() {RequestUri = _statusMonitorUri};
                    try
                    {
                        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, new CancellationToken());
                        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            _isOffline = false;
                            _timer.Dispose();
                        } 
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }
                }, null, new TimeSpan(0,0,0),new TimeSpan(0,1,0));

            }

            private HttpResponseMessage OfflineResponse(HttpRequestMessage request)
            {
                if (_offlineResponses.ContainsKey(request.RequestUri))
                {
                    return _offlineResponses[request.RequestUri];
                }
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable);
            }
        }
    }
```