# HttpClient.GetStringAsync blocking in console app

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I have written a method using `HttpClient`:

```
private static async Task<string> DownloadString(string url)
{
    var uri = new Uri(url);

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        HttpRequestHeaders headers = client.DefaultRequestHeaders;
        headers.Accept.ParseAdd("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        headers.AcceptEncoding.ParseAdd("gzip, deflate");
        headers.AcceptLanguage.ParseAdd("en-US,en;q=0.5");
        headers.Connection.ParseAdd("keep-alive");
        headers.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0");
        headers.Host = uri.Host;

        return await client.GetStringAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Then I am calling it in the `Main` method of a Console application like so:

```
Console.WriteLine("Downloading");
string dom = DownloadString("http://www.shaanig.org/f8/index1.html").Result;
Console.WriteLine(dom);
```

All works fine if I have internet connection, or if it runs while I don't have internet connection (In which case, it throws an exception). But if I disconnect my internet while it is in downloading, it just hangs there. No exceptions. It just hangs.

Can someone explain to me what is going on here? And how can I fix this?

Comment: have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696320/checking-internet-connection-with-httpclient

Comment: @DavidHaim, while trying to define that, I found that it throws after a whopping 100 seconds.

Comment: @EmperorAiman and when you shutdown the interenet, about how many seconds after the request had statrted have passed?

Comment: @DavidHaim I shut it down after like 1 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must use HttpClient.Timeout Property.

In HttpClient construction, you can use :

```
var client = new HttpClient() 
{ 
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200) 
};
```

Comment: the http requests already have a default timeout set by .Net itself.. this has no meaning

Comment: @DavidHaim, looks like it is by default 100 seconds. Didn't know it was that long...

Answer (score 1):

> while trying to define that, I found that it throws after a whopping 100 seconds.
>
> I shut it down after like 1 seconds

so, there is not bug/hang.
on Windows, .Net uses the underlying native `WinHttp` API to make the http requests.

if we look at the [.Net Code which calls WinHttp](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler/src/System/Net/Http/WinHttpHandler.cs) we see that

```
private TimeSpan _connectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
private TimeSpan _sendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
private TimeSpan _receiveHeadersTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
private TimeSpan _receiveDataTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
```

if you block the internet about one second after the request has begun, it will take about 30~60 seconds in order for the timeout to be fired.

Comment: It's actually 100 seconds. `The default value is 100,000 milliseconds (100 seconds).`

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off changing it from a static to an instance class, and then running it on a separate thread. You will run into trouble when using Static classes and multiple threads.

Secondly, why are you calling ConfigureAwait here:

```
return await client.GetStringAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

You're using the async/await pattern so you don't need to use that.

Comment: `ConfigureAwait` is the best practise if I don't want to capture the synchronization context..
I doubt using an instance method will work. Also, if it's async, why would I start a new thread?